# Calculating mean, std.dev and variance and creating a new data frame from these calculations in python

Tags: python, dataframe

My dataframe

```
date   Stk A     Stk B  Stk C   Stk D
01.01   0.03    0.0102  0.034   0.083232
02.02   0.05    0.017   0.0578  0.13872
03.03   0.04    0.0136  0.046   0.110976
04.04   0.006   0.00204 0.006   0.0166464
```

---

Required output

```
           Stk A      Stk B       Stk C     Stk D
Mean     0.0315      0.01071    0.036       0.0873936
Std.Dev  0.0188      0.0064     0.021       0.052322762
Variance 0.0003      0.0034     0.047       0.002737671
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Using pandas library in python

```
import pandas as pd
stats=pd.DataFrame()
stats["mean"]=data.mean()
stats["Std.Dev"]=data.std()
stats["Var"]=data.var()
```

And then transpose it like

```
stats.T
```

Comment: But what is 'data'?

Answer (score 8):

df.describe() will do the trick.

```
my_df.describe()

                Age
count  37471.000000  
mean      43.047317      
std       20.676562      
min        1.000000     
25%       28.000000     
50%       43.000000     
75%       59.000000 
max      117.000000
```

Answer (score 2):

You can do something like this:

**option 1**

```
pd.DataFrame([df.mean(), df.std(), df.var()], index=['Mean', 'Std. dev', 'Variance'])
```

or something like this:

**option 2**

```
df2 = df.describe().loc[['mean', 'std']]
df2.loc['variance'] = df2.loc['std']**2
```